# How to get unspents for a specified bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client

I want to access unspent data of a specific bitcoin address.

I am trying this command

bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent "some bitcoin address"

But I am always getting an empty list. I am using local bitcoind server on windows 7.

What should I do or use any function for getting desired output ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`listunspent` only displays information about addresses which are currently part of your wallet. Bitcoin Core does not maintain indexes of unspent outputs for addresses you do not own, and will simply return a blank set if you attempt to query for them.

Comment: Does `txindex=1` help in any way for `listunspent`?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the list unspent of a specific bitcoin address( not belongs to your wallet), you must first import the address to wallet using **[importaddress](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress)**
 This RPC does not require the private key of that address. Note that this will cause the program to rescan the entire blockchain, which will take several minutes.

now you can use the listunspent call to get the UTXO.

Edit: use rescan : true if you are importing already existing address

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. I get an empty result array when I run listunspent rpc call

Comment: Do you imported the address?

Comment: Yes I did. 
What happens is when I importeadress I get this response
```{
  result: null,
  error: null,
  id: 'd542c95d-ad8f-4a8e-b92f-6a69fa051e9d'
}
```

And then when I try to listunsent I get 
```{ result: [], error: null, id: '460bdaa4-5209-4dc8-ba76-582e3e0cc0e4' }```

Comment: hi @JosephAkayesi, The response is totally fine. you should enable rescan option if the address already have some unspents.  eg:bitcoin-cli importaddress "myaddress" "testing" true. You can reffer here : https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress

Comment: Wow. I read that rescans can take forever. For my use case I need to be able to read unspent values in less than at least 10 secs

Comment: Even after using rescan option I still get the same result. Do you have any idea where I can find the bitcoin.conf that is ideal for a bitcoin exchange applicatiom

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/listunspent), you can first get the addresses of an account using `getaddressesbyaccount` and then list all the unspent of those addresses using

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 6 9999999 "[\"1PGFqEzfmQch1gKD3ra4k18PNj3tTUUSqg\",\"1LtvqCaApEdUGFkpKMM4MstjcaL4dKg8SP\"]"
```

where 6 and 9999999 are the `min` and `max` confirmations

Comment: OP is asking about arbitrary addresses, not just those in his wallet.

Comment: oh.. my mistake :)   
hope this might help people who are looking to get unspent from the wallet addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a program that allows you to search for any address whether it belongs to your wallet or not, in Python3.

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/ORP967/Bitcoin_Core_RPC_par_address

Let me know if you guys have any improvements that can be made to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the addresses are in your wallet, you're looking for `listreceivedbyaddress`. That will give you back this:

> Returns an array of objects containing:
>
> - "address" : receiving address
> - "account" : the account of the receiving address
> - "amount" : total amount received by the address
> - "confirmations" : number of confirmations of the most recent transaction included
> - "txids" : a list of transaction IDs that you can pass to `gettransaction` in order to see the full transaction.

[(Source.)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: Yup, But if i want to get unspents of an address which is not a part of my wallet ? than what function should i use ? @Nick

Comment: @HassanMehmood Doesn't exist. Use bitcoin-abe or electrum server or blockchain.info instead.

Comment: Hey, from answers, I added one my multisig add using this command "addmultisigaddress". and sent some satoshis to this address. but I am still getting empty list after calling :listunspent" ???

Comment: @HassanMehmood You need to rerun with rescan. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/what-exactly-did-bitcoin-qt-rescan-reindex-do/22224#22224

Comment: I did rerun with rescan, but still getting empty list.. @Nick

Comment: @HassanMehmood Are there any unspents at that address? Has the rescan finished?

Comment: Yup, There are some unspents, This is the address "31zeoskE8zeyQARFEVzwJzsp7GQpLn5zhF"
and I started the server using
bitcoind.exe -daemon -rescan -debugnet -printtoconsole

Comment: And Yes i think the rescan is finished!

Comment: but still getting empty list. :/

Comment: Now I sent some btc to one of other addresses that are showing me while running command "getaddressesbyaccount". and after that i run the cmd "listunspent 0" so it shows that transaction.

But after that I again send some btc to my mulisig address which I have added using addmultisigadress cmd. But listunspent not showing any unspent related to multisig ? Why ?

Comment: addmultisigaddress is not enough to make the wallet treat the address as its own; you also need to have all of the private keys. If you want to treat an address as yours regardless of keys, use importaddress.

Answer (score 0):

Unspent data appears in **Unspent List** only after SIX confirmations.

Try this command,

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent "some bitcoin address" 0
```

It will show all the unspent transactions.

Comment: I am running the same command but getting empty list in response. I first generated and added a multisig address using "addultisigaddress" command and call listunspent. But in result i always get an empty list though I sent some satoshis to this address 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Other options, beyond what Nick mentioned, are to either use the toshi.io API:

[toshi.io - API - utxo's for address](https://toshi.io/docs/#get-address-unspent-outputs)

Or run your own toshi node:

[toshi.io](https://toshi.io/)

Comment: https://chain.com is also very good and easy to use! but i was trying not to use any 3rd party APIs.

Comment: @HassanMehmood if running the toshi node locally isn't something you want either (it consumes well over 200GB of space) then you could run bitcoin core with txindex enabled. You'd then have to parse the blockchain and build and keep up a database of utxo yourself. As others have pointed out, if you just want a bitcoin-cli argument for this, it doesn't exist.